# Why does Users & Groups System Preference not display a user?

Tags: macos, user-account

There's a user from whom I inherited my work Mac who is listed under the /Users directory, however, this user doesn't appear in the Users & Groups system preference. I am an admin on the Mac so I don't think that it's a permissions issue. Does anybody know why this may be happening?

FYI: My ultimate goal is to delete this user to free up disk space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the user was deleted, but the user's home folder was retained (See the option **Don't change the home folder** below).

It can be deleted if you don't need it. An offline backup of the computer or /users folder can also free you to delete the files knowing you could go back if needed.

[image]